# Drop-down values to store in database

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have created a app in which there are 3 spinners(drop-down),one is for days,2nd is for months and 3rd is for years.I wanted to stored the values user select in the database(sqlite) for example 3/August/1992.How can i achieve it.

Comment: y dont you use a date picker?

Answer (score 1):

U can do as below:-

```
spinner= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerId);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position,long id)
                {
                      spinner.setSelection(position);
                      String selectedRole = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

                      Log.v("", "Spinner position: "+position);

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


                }
            });
```

This is for one Drop/down, U can use same for orther two.

**Second Option** :-

If you want than you can user DatePicker as dialog also as below :-

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And

```
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker dp, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
            String strDate = GlobalVariables.formatter4Display.format(new Date(
                    c.getTimeInMillis()));
            tvDob.setText(strDate);
}}
```

I hope this will help u.

Comment: so should i use selectedRole variable to store in the database??

Comment: Ya.. U can change this variable as day than again use same code for month with some chnages and make another variable in it as month... and in last merge that 3 variable and than store it in DB.

Comment: tysm for your help,but i m confused to whether hw to merge all the stuffs like day/month/year